# how to make google maps like button?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openlayers

i want to add button to my personal app. like google maps has at right side of maps which writing on it Map and on mouseover Earth.

can i do this with openlayers control like OpenLayers.Control.TYPE_TOGGLE with adding listeners or with anything else javascript...?

thanks for your helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to have a look at this
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html

if you are trying to achieve something like this

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom.html

Comment: thanks. is there anything for adding something on openlayers?